# How to install Readahead-Fedora on Lubuntu 15.10?

Tags: fedora, apt, lubuntu

I try to install Readahead-Fedora withe the command line :

```
sudo apt-get install readahead-fedora
```

But doesn't work!

How can I install readahead-fedora?

Comment: what is *"But doesn't work!"*?

Comment: The command line doesn't install readahead

Comment: and what *does* it on your machine?

Comment: No package readahead-fedora available.

Comment: so are you trying to install `readahead` or `readahead-fedora`?

Comment: I try to install readahead-fedora

Comment: So why do you have error `No package readahead available.`?

Comment: Sorry , the  error is : No package readahead-fedora available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last Ubuntu version having [readahead-fedora was 15.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/readahead-fedora), according to ubuntu.packages.

Ubuntu 15.10 came up with `systemd` which changed the boot process so `readahead-fedora` is no longer applicable.

Comment: @garethTheRed Sure. Thank you for the note. Fixed now.